# Android Paging 3 With RemoteMediator, can't add header or footer

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-3

When I put RemoteMediator in the Pager constructor, header or footer is not showing, only work when I remove the RemoteMediator. May I know is this a bug for Paging 3? Thanks.

Comment: This is a known bug in alpha08 and alpha09. It will be addressed in alpha11 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172254056

Comment: @dlam ahhh I see, thanks a lot mate!!